# XML Parsing + Any way to write TestCase for XML Parsing

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, xml-parsing, rake-task

Can any one suggest, How to write test case for XML value.. when it is parsed in Rake Task ?

Here, In my project I took XML file from third party and parse that XML in my rake task and that rake task store that value in defined database and table. So now I wanna write few test case for this task.

Please suggest some thing??

For Rails 3.0.4, RSpec as Testing Framework

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have the parser within some kind of class, let's say:

```
class MyApp::XmlImporter
  def initialize(file)
    @file = file
  end

  def parse
    ...
  end
end
```

Then add a file to your spec folder spec/lib/my_app/xml_importer_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper' do

describe MyApp::XmlImporter do
  it "should import the test file" do
    described_class.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/test_file.xml").parse

    # Now you check for the correct database state given your test_file.xml
  end
end
```